# What is the state of research on finding all prime knots with 17 crossings?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, open-problems

In [this 1998 journal paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20110407072028/http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/101/05/html/home/pdf/first.pdf), all the prime knots with 16 or fewer crossings are found (some of which were found earlier by others).  There are over 1.7 million such knots.  But the prime knots with 17 crossings have not yet been tabulated.  Here is what [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=RqiMCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA34&dq=%2217%20crossings%22%20knots&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false) says:

> This is probably hard and requires new ideas.

But this book was written in 2004, so things may have changed since then.  There have certainly been a lot of developments in knot theory over the past 15 years.

So my question is, what is the state of research on finding all prime knots with 17 crossings?  Are we relatively close to doing so, and have partial results been discovered?

Comment: Is there a reason that 17 is qualitatively different than 16? This question suggests that planarity of the Dowker code starts to become rare. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19745/counting-knots-with-fixed-number-of-crossings

Comment: The problem of tabulating knots via minimal-crossing diagrams, at this point, is less about mathematics and more about accounting.  How do you keep track of such vast quantities of data?   Provided you can store the data, we have the algorithms to compare and deal with duplicates.  Given that 19-crossing knots have over 300-million distinct types, the quantity of redundant diagrams must be astronomical.

Comment: Dear Ryan - Yes, organising the data (of the 19 crossing census) is a huge task. However, the “dealing with duplicates” is also highly non-trivial. Ben has said that with each increase in crossing number he finds new difficult examples that require mathematical work.

Comment: @SamNead: I agree, but it's mathematics that's all set up.  Finite index subgroup enumeration and interfacing Regina with GAP is something that is fairly direct -- Regina used to interface with GAP, in some of its first iterations.  I had been planning to extend that line of reasoning to build the corresponding covering spaces (triangulated) but I did not finish that project.  Curious to see if Ben did that as well.   Scanning the paper it looks like the diagram moves must be some of the most recent coding additions.

Answer (score 17):

Ben Burton has found that there are 352,152,252 prime non-trivial knots with up to 19 crossings. See [here](https://regina-normal.github.io/data.html) for the tables.

2022-06-11 update: The details of this enumeration have now been published in a [conference proceedings](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.SoCG.2020.25). It describes the variety of algorithmic techniques that were required, and the pairs of knots that were most difficult to distinguish.

Comment: Why isn’t this major news?  Why hasn’t this result been published in journals?

Comment: I believe it is currently being written up. I saw him give a talk about this result at a recent conference.

Comment: It does say on that page that the paper would appear on arXiv in June 2018, so what happened?

Comment: Things sometimes take longer than expected, as I'm sure every mathematician has experienced first-hand. If the precise details matter to you, you can of course e-mail Ben.

Comment: If you think a one year lag on a paper is unusual, you must be young.  I've got a pre-print that I've been getting ready for publication for the past 11 years...